# Angular routing locks me in one component and I can't route out of the current url

Tags: angular

I created a method that reads the value of an item and reroutes to a new component with the logic below

```
  navigate_to_page(url) {
    
    console.log(url)
   
    console.log(['../' + url])
    this.route.navigate(['../' + url])
  }
```

When I first log in I go to the dashboard component and can move to any other component.
When I change report types I do not change components. However, if I want to go to the dashboard or settings page (a separate component) I cannot leave the report component.

EDIT:
Injection Site in

```
constructor(private location: Location, private dataService: ListdataService, private route: Router,private timer: TimerService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private sharedService: SharedService, private httpClient: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) { }
```

Comment: What is route of type? can you show how you are injecting it?

Comment: @BDB what do you mean by route type?

Comment: You must have injected route in constructor parameter. Simply hover over route anywhere in page and see what is it's type.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your project. It's likely that you are running into the difference between navigate and navigateByUrl.

NavigateByUrl takes absolute URL's which I think will solve your issue. e.g.

```
this.route.navigateByUrl(['/dashboard'])
```

Will take you to /dashboard no matter where you are in the project or what your current URL is.

Comment: what could it mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like  below

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '' , redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'report' , component: ReportComponent},
{ path: 'dashboard' , component: DashBoardComponent}
];
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  constructor( private router: Router  ) { }

  navigate_to_page(url: string) {
  this.router.navigate(['/' + url]) //pass 'report' as the value of url
  }
```

report.component.ts

```
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  constructor( private router: Router  ) { }

  navigate_to_page(url: string) {
  this.router.navigate(['/' + url]) //pass 'dashboard' as the value of url
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have incorrectly injected the router. Check the [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-jdmri1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) project that I have created by including your method and It's working properly. Notice in following portion,

```
 constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

,

```
  this.router.navigate([url]);
```

and

```
<a (click)="navigate_to_page('/login')">Login</a>
```

Also, you can call navigate_to_page method from anywhere in your component.

Comment: I have it Injected correctly still no luck

Comment: did you compare your project with the one I have associated with stackblitz  link?